# WPF custom control: How to assign the category "Text" to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf

Some native WPF controls have a property category "Text" under which they are listed in the properties inspector, when "Arrange by: Category" is active. But when I try to set this category for a property of my WPF custom control using

```cs
[Category("Text")]
```

it does not work. The property does not appear in any category. (Tested with VS 2015.)

This is in accordance with the fact that `System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute` does not include a Text category.

But how is it then possible to associate a property with the Text category?

**Edit:** For clarification, here is the relevant part of the implementation of the property in the original code:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

...

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty;

...

[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Text")]
[Description("Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the text editing control is read-only to a user interacting with the control.")]
public bool IsReadOnly
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
  set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using a Dependency Property. If not try typing in **dependencyproperty** and hit tab (or enter). Then define its type and name.

Then you may find these lines of code and add your attribute like this:

```
[Description("Your Description"), Category("Text")]
public string PropName {
     get { return (string)GetValue(PropNameProperty); }
     set { SetValue(PropNameProperty, value); 
}
```

Comment: Your proposal does not work. Of course I am using a `DependencyProperty`. But even if I would not, it makes no difference. Using the category "Behavior" instead of "Text" the property appears as expected independent from being associated with a `DependencyProperty` or not. Adding a description makes also no difference.